# What is the most efficient way to store and query a large group (10,000+) strings?

Tags: ios, swift

So I have 10,000+ Strings and I need to query if any given string is contained within this group. I currently have them just stored in an array and I just use `stringArray.contains(myString)` functionality. Is this efficient? I'm storing this array in a seperate class and file, but it does seem quite "ugly" to have such a massive array

Comment: 10,000+ Strings should be store in some kinds of database, not array, how can you get it everytime your app run anyway? Fetch 10k strings from server everytime app run?

Comment: No, the strings are constant and will be stored locally.

Comment: @Tj3n Depending on the length, 10,000 strings is really not much. If they averaged 1000 characters each, that's only 10 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I progressed, the number of Strings exceeded 1.5mil and I didn't want to store those just in a massive swift file. So i created a JSON file for it and created a singleton that parsed the data from the JSON when the app launched. This was exceedingly slow though, so I moved to the option of storing it in a SQLite database which I ship with the app. I then used the following library to search:

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to do `contains` checks, and don't care about element ordering, use a [`Set`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set).

```
let someStrings: Set = ["a", "b", "c"]
print(someStrings.contains("a"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The bigger question you may have to face is how to retrieve a string you might want. I suggest you look into indexing by trigraphs contained in the string. In particular, identify all of the sequences of three characters that occur in a string, and index that string by the least common trigraph it contains.

You could build that table of frequencies  yourself from your corpus of strings or, if I remember correctly, you can find general purpose tables of trigraph frequencies on the net, although I don’t have a link handy here with my phone.